# Capturing themes, actors, random thoughts about films and videos

Tags: database

I'm watching numerous snippets of film and video, looking for themes, especially. Some of these items will recur quite often and I don't want to retype them. Is there a nice bit of software, preferably free, that is nimble enough that it won't distract me from watching the films?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a spreadsheet with specified values for each field?